# How to restrict node delete through url in drupal

Tags: url, drupal, nodes

How to restrict node delete through url I have tried already one code.

I have tried through menu alter, access callback false
But when I use this code it is restrict but it is also restrict through delete button.
Please refer me  any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can restrict the action in that way.

The delete link/button is just a normal GET request, just like entering a URL.

If you alter the menu item for node deletion, you will alter both the URL and button/link behavior.